# CPU graph not functioning properly

Tags: linux, cpu, conky, graph

My conky's cpu graph appears to not be functioning properly. It is just a block as per the screenshot that does not respond to actual cpu usage. Kind of annoying. I have also attached my conkyrc. I honestly don't know why this isn't working right. Thanks...[image: Screenshot]

```
    conky.config = {

background = true,
update_interval = 1,

cpu_avg_samples = 2,
net_avg_samples = 2,
temperature_unit = 'celsius',

double_buffer = true,
no_buffers = true,
text_buffer_size = 2048,

gap_x = 80,
gap_y = 70,
minimum_width = 350, minimum_height = 1100,
maximum_width = 375,
own_window = true,
own_window_type = 'desktop',
own_window_transparent = true,
own_window_argb_visual = true,

own_window_type = 'normal',
own_window_class = 'conky-semi',
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below',
border_inner_margin = 0,
border_outer_margin = 0,
alignment = 'top_right',


draw_shades = false,
draw_outline = false,
draw_borders = false,
draw_graph_borders = false,

override_utf8_locale = true,
use_xft = true,
font = 'Neuropolitical:size=10',
xftalpha = 0.5,
uppercase = false,

-- Defining colors
default_color = '#00FFFF',
-- Shades of Gray
color1 = '#00BEBE',
color2 = '#009696',
color3 = '#007878',
 -- Orange
color4 = '#00FFFF',
 -- Green
color5 = '#FF3C00',
-- Loading lua script for drawning rings
lua_load = '~/.conky/seamod_rings.lua',
lua_draw_hook_pre = 'main',

};

--${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}${pre_exec lsb_release -d | cut -f 2} - $sysname $kernel
conky.text = [[
${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color4}SYSTEM ${hr 2}
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}${execi 6500 lsb_release -d | cut -f 2} - $sysname $kernel
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}Battery:  ${color3}${battery_bar 5,150 BAT0} ${color3}${battery_percent BAT0}%
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}Uptime: ${color3}$uptime

# Showing CPU Graph
${voffset 25}
${offset 125}${cpugraph cpu0 40,220 009696 009696 -0.5 -l}${voffset -25}
${offset 90}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color5}CPU
# Showing TOP 5 CPU-consumers
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color4}${top name 1}${alignr}${top cpu 1}%
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}${top name 2}${alignr}${top cpu 2}%
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${top name 3}${alignr}${top cpu 3}%
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color3}${top name 4}${alignr}${top cpu 4}%
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color3}${top name 5}${alignr}${top cpu 5}%

#Showing memory part with TOP 5
${voffset 47}
${offset 90}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color5}MEM
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color4}${top_mem name 1}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 1}
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color1}${top_mem name 2}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 2}
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${top_mem name 3}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 3}
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 4}
${offset 105}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color3}${top_mem name 4}${alignr}${top_mem mem_res 5}

# Showing disk partitions: root, home and files
${voffset 12}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}Disk Read: ${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_read}
${offset 180}${color1}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}Disk Write: ${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${color2}${diskio_write}
${voffset -23}
${offset 90}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color5}DISKS
${offset 120}${diskiograph 33,220 009696 009696}${voffset -30}
${voffset 20}
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /}
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /home}${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /home}
${offset 15}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Free: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_free /}${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Used: $color3${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}${fs_used /}
# Network data (my desktop have only LAN). ETHERNET ring is mostly useless but looks pretty, main info is in the graphs
${voffset 40}
${offset 200}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color1}Lan IP: ${alignr}$color3${addr wlp3s0} 
${offset 200}${font Neuropolitical:size=9:style=bold}${color1}Ext IP: ${alignr}$color3${execi 3600 wget -q -O /dev/stdout http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | cut -d : -f 2- | cut -d \< -f -1} 
${voffset -36}
${offset 90}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}${color5}WIRELESS
${voffset 40}             
${offset 15}${color1}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}Up: ${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}$color2${upspeed wlp3s0} / ${totalup wlp3s0}
${offset 15}${upspeedgraph wlp3s0 40,320 007878 009696 1280KiB -l}
${offset 15}${color1}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=bold}Down: ${alignr}${font Neuropolitical:size=10:style=normal}$color2${downspeed wlp3s0} / ${totaldown wlp3s0}
${offset 15}${downspeedgraph wlp3s0 40,320 007878 009696 1280KiB -l}

${color4}${hr 2}




]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
${cpugraph cpu0 40,220 009696 009696 -0.5 -l}
```

I'm not sure what a scale of -0.5 and logarithm mode means when together, but it seems to work for me (Conky 1.9.1), i.e. not a solid bar. I would have thought you would get a better idea of what the cpu is doing with a simple linear scale which might work, ie

```
${cpugraph cpu0 40,220 009696 009696}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I didn't know what it meant either, i am a bit of a newbie when it comes to conky. Anyway the cpu graph is working properly now thank you @meuh

Comment: Errm I'm not sure what the log thing would do, so could you send a screenshot or something of how it looks like

Comment: Oh I just found my conky is really out of date its 1.10.1 :)

Comment: The `-l` logarithm mode is just supposed to mean that small values are magnified so you can see something changing rather than just a few pixels when your cpu use is only 3 or 4%. The problem I have is with the scale value, which is not well documented. Without `-l` a scale of 100 seems to mean 100% cpu use will use the full height of the graph, but with `-l` it may mean something else, though I don't know what. So I stick to a default linear scale where at least I know what values I am seeing. Perhaps your more *uptodate* doc has more info.